# YARN components

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

What is

1. Node manager
2. Container
3. App Master

in YARN ( Map Reduce 2.0 ) ?

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html

Also would like to know why there is no application master in bottom box of diagram of above link ?

I am not looking for what it does but what it is !!
( like => Not sure if container means like spring container ( that means list of jar files ? ) or its server like web server ? Is application master mean simply Java class ? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Node Manager is the per-machine framework agent who is responsible for launching the applications’ containers, monitoring their resource usage (cpu, memory, disk, network) and reporting the same to the Scheduler.

Container is an abstract notion which incorporates elements such as memory, cpu, disk, network etc - from [MapReduce_NextGen_Architecture](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12486023/MapReduce_NextGen_Architecture.pdf). It could be regarded as a serializable Java object including below information

```
message ContainerProto {
optional ContainerIdProto id = 1;
optional NodeIdProto nodeId = 2;
optional string node_http_address = 3;
optional ResourceProto resource = 4;
optional PriorityProto priority = 5;
optional hadoop.common.TokenProto container_token = 6;
}
```

The application master for MapReduce jobs is a Java application whose main class is MRAppMaster - from "Hadoop - The Definitive Guide"

Comment: Thanks for information,Can you elaborate more on Node Manager? what mean by framework agent ? when you say scheduler means resource manager ?

Comment: Scheduler is a part of Resource Manager. Please see more explanations at the link I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Container means bundle or set of resources like RAM,CPU, disk, network etc on every node.

NodeManager is like Tasktracker in Hadoop 1.x, which is slave node for Hadoop Cluster for Mapreduce.

ApplicationMaster is per application master that monitors the job lifecycle and negotiate with ResourceManager(same as JobTracker in Hadoop 1.x) for the resources.

In Hadoop 2.0(YARN) role of Jobtracker is got divided into two parts.

1. A global ResourceManger.
2. Per Application an ApplicationMaster.

Per Node slave is NodeManger.

NodeManager launches the container from the help of ResourceManager and ApplicationMaster for running Map and Reduce tasks.

With Hadoop 2.x Jobtarcker and Tasktracker both are obsolete.